# bootstrap font not reflecting - for bootswatch theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, themes, google-font-api

I'm very noob in bootstrap. I tried my first bootstrap page and then downloaded a theme from bootswatch.com and replaced the bootstrap.css with the Cerulean theme. When I change the font in the bootstrap.css it stay with the old theme

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing);
```

but its not reflecting when I refresh my page.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Twitter Bootstrap Tutorial - A responsive layout tutorial</title>
<style type='text/css'>

</style>
<script>
$(function() {
  // Setup drop down menu
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

  // Fix input element click problem
  $('.dropdown input, .dropdown label').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container"><!-- Collapsable nav bar -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Your site name for the upper left corner of the site -->
      <a class="brand">GUVI</a>

      <!-- Start of the nav bar content -->
      <div class="nav-collapse"><!-- Other nav bar content -->


        <!-- The drop down menu -->
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
              <form action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user[username]" size="30" />
  <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="user[password]" size="30" />
  <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
  <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>

  <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
</form>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you changed the less files, you have to recompile them.

Comment: Did you type it correctly? Shouldn't it be `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing);`

Comment: I can't really tell anything from this code but be sure that a) the file you replaced is the correct file being referenced, and b) you've cleared your cache (normally a shift+refresh will do). You mention changing the font, but are you also changing the font-family names in the css?

Comment: @ArmanH The double // is fine, and is protocol independent.

Comment: @BotskoNet Never knew that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're linking to the right font, yeah; that said, here's my take on this:

1. In most cases you should use a  tag to import Google web fonts. I generally avoid using @import where possible because it delays the loading of the file.
2. All you should need to do to replace the font is to specify the new font-family as 'Caesar Dressing' inside a body {} style block. Assuming you've already done that in your local copy of bootstrap.css, if that still doesn't work try specifying it inside a  tag inside your HTML. You should avoid doing that where possible though; it makes it annoying down the road when you have multiple pages to maintain.

One other thing: I noticed you have some inline styles for some of your inputs. You should really avoid using those where possible--it's good form to try and separate presentation and content markup as much as possible.